# Forcing a point to be rational by base changing by a normal extension of fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $F|k$ be a field extension (of finite type if necessary), and $L|k$ a finite normal field extension such that $L$ contains $F$. Are all the residue fields of $F\otimes_kL$ isomorphic to $L$? I suspect that the answer is yes, but I only know how to prove it when $F|k$ is finite separable.

Comment: What does the term residue field mean in the context of $F\otimes_k L$? Is this a local ring?

Comment: No. It is not local (though it is an artinian ring). By residue fields of this ring I understand the quotients of the ring by any of its maximal ideals (in general, the residue fields of its localizations at prime ideals).

Comment: can you pick $L=k$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that I forgot to state that $L$ contains $F$. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Let $S$ be the set of minimal polynomials of elements of $F$ over $k$.  Note that then $F\otimes_k L$ is generated as an $L$-algebra by elements which are roots of elements of $S$.  It follows that if $K$ is any residue field of $F\otimes_k L$, the same is true of $K$.  But since $F\subseteq L$ and $L$ is normal, every element of $S$ splits in $L$.  Thus all of the generators of $K$ are actually already elements of $L$, so $K=L$.